# How will make variable to do_shortcode value? i want to change shortcode value like (category="others") how it possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I want to make variables of these red block parts
([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOg6e.png)).

PHP code:

```
echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="others" per_page="12" columns="4"]');
```

Comment: it's hard to understand what you are asking. why don't you just replace the text with variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly insert variable values in a `""` delimited string in PHP.

```
$cat = "some_category";
$per = 20; // some number
$col = 10; // some number

echo do_shortcode("[product_category category=\"$cat\" per_page=\"$per\" columns=\"$col\"]");
```

If you still want to use a `''` delimited string, you need to append values together.

```
echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="' . $cat . '" per_page="' . $per . '" columns="' . $col . '"]');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i am great full to you for your help.

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as accepted and upvote if you like.